# why clone method and finalize method in object class are protected?

Tags: java

why only clone method and finalize method in object class are protected?

I didn't understand what is the cause behind this.

Comment: better to ask at [Programmers@StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: And similarly for clone. With a copy paste of your question into Google, you would've found your answer.